# Is it mandatory to provide a default locale.properties or @DefaultStringValue while using gwt internationalization?

Tags: gwt

I am using Static String Internationalization.

`Locale.java`

```
public interface Locale extends Constants{

String kbps();
```

}

`Locale_en.properties`

```
kbps=Kbps1
```

Both are in the same package. In `.gwt.xml`, included following line:

`<extend-property name="locale" values="en"/>`

Now when I am compiling the code, i'm getting following error:

```
com.google.gwt.i18n.rebind.AbstractResource$MissingResourceException: No resource found for key 'kbps'
```

The above error goes away if I provide Locale.properties or @DefaultStringValue for the key. any idea why the gwt compile-time error is coming even if I am specifying the locale in the module XML?

Answer (score 1):

Use `<set-property-fallback name="locale" value="en"/>` to define a default locale in your project

Answer (score 0):

With extend-property, the "default" locale is still present, you are merely adding the "en" locale to the list of possible locales.